# Section between two circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw the following picture, but I'm having trouble with the region between the two circles

[image]

I've been trying to use `scope` however I'm only able to fill the whole intersection.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[->][thin,color=blue] (0,0) -- (-3,0) coordinate[label = {below:$y$}];
\draw[->][thin,color=blue]  (0,0) -- (0,3) coordinate[label = {right:$x$}];
\draw[->][thin,color=blue]  (0,0) -- (3,-3) coordinate[label = {left:$z$}];

\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (2.25cm);


\def\circleone{ (0,0) circle (2cm) }
\def\circletwo{ (0,0) circle (2.25cm) }


\begin{scope}

\clip \circletwo;

\fill[white, opacity=0.2] \circleone;

\end{scope}

\begin{scope}

\clip
\circleone
(current bounding box.south west) rectangle
(current bounding box.north east);
\fill[blue,opacity=0.2] \circletwo;

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, do you mean you have problems with that little red bit at the top of the circle?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to fill the whole circle just that red section above.

Comment: This may be a bug (or bad thinking on my part): The manual states that for self-intersecting paths, the even odd rule applies when it comes to clipping; That is, if you have an even number of clipping areas overlapping, it does not clip. Hence `\clip (0,0) circle (2) circle (2.25);` should work, but it doesn't. Work-around: `\clip (0,0) circle (2.25); \clip (0,0) circle (2) (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);` followed by whatever you want to clip in your area. (Inside a scope)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the easiest way.  Slightly more complicated would be to make the sides vertical rather than angled.  There was nothing to indicate how wide to make it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[->][thin,color=blue] (0,0) -- (-3,0) coordinate[label = {below:$y$}];
\draw[->][thin,color=blue]  (0,0) -- (0,3) coordinate[label = {right:$x$}];
\draw[->][thin,color=blue]  (0,0) -- (3,-3) coordinate[label = {left:$z$}];

\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (2.25cm);

\fill[blue,opacity=0.2] (85: 2cm) arc[radius=2cm, start angle=85, end angle=95]
  -- (95: 2.25cm) arc[radius=2.25cm, start angle=95, end angle=85] -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 5):

Here is another suggestion using the `even odd rule` for the blue filling. The red part is added as path picture.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[->][thin,color=blue] (O) -- +(-3,0) coordinate[label = {below:$y$}];
\draw[->][thin,color=blue] (O) -- +(0,3) coordinate[label = {right:$x$}];
\draw[->][thin,color=blue] (O) -- +(3,-3) coordinate[label = {left:$z$}];

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[even odd rule,fill=blue,fill opacity=.2]
  [path picture={\fill[red,opacity=1](O)+(-.2,0)rectangle+(.2,0|-current bounding box.north);}]
  (O)
  circle [radius=2]
  circle[radius=2.25]
;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get the axis on top I have drawn them in a background layer. Instead you could draw the axis after the circles.

Additionally I have replaced all the `(0,0)` by the already defined `(O)` and then I have used coordinates relative to `(O)`.

Answer (score 5):

One more alternative:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 ax/.style = {->, thin,color=blue},
                    ]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
% circle
\draw[double=blue!30,double distance=2.5mm,thick]       
            (O) circle (21.25mm);
% arc segment
\filldraw[semithick,red!50]
            (85:2.01) arc[radius=2.01, start angle=85, end angle=95] --
            (95:2.24) arc[radius=2.24, start angle=95, end angle=85] -- cycle;
% axes
\draw[ax]   (O) -- (-3,0) node[below] {$y$};
\draw[ax]   (O) -- ( 0,3) node[left]  {$x$};
\draw[ax]   (O) -- (3,-3) node[right] {$z$};
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or slightly simpler:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 ax/.style = {->, thin,color=blue},
                    ]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
% circle
\draw[double=blue!30,double distance=2.5mm,thick]       
            (O) circle (21.25mm);
% arc segment
\draw[double=red!50,double distance=2.5mm,thick]
            (85:21.25mm) arc[radius=21.25mm, start angle=85, end angle=95];
% axes
\draw[ax]   (O) -- (-3,0) node[below] {$y$};
\draw[ax]   (O) -- ( 0,3) node[left]  {$x$};
\draw[ax]   (O) -- (3,-3) node[right] {$z$};
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]